# R - d3heatmap - ordering rownames and X axis

Tags: r

Original `df1` has 3 columns: `Dia`, `Visita`, `Hora`. In order to make a heatmap, i needed to reshape it from `long` to `wide`.

Once having the wide `df2` (from `df1`). I've made a heatmap with:

```
d3heatmap(df2, scale = "column", colors = "Blues")
```

But: I need to

1) order the rownames from: "Domingo", "Lunes" ... to "Sábado". And put them to the left of the graphic.
2) order the X axis from 0 to 24 hours.

*I would also like to remove the "deograms"? (I don't know how to name those squares, up and left)

[image]

I've tried converting the `df1` columns: `Dia` and `Horas` to factor. But that didn't help me after with the ordering of the rows and x axis.

```
df1$Dia <- factor(df$Dia,
                         levels = c("Domingo", "Lunes",
                                    "Martes","Miércoles",
                                    "Jueves","Viernes",
                                    "Sábado"), 
                         ordered = T)



df1$Hora <- factor(df1$Hora,
                         levels = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,
                                    7,8,9,10,11,12,
                                    13,14,15,16,17,
                                    18,19,20,21,22,
                                    23,24), 
                         ordered = T)
```

Comment: I think you can turn off the dendrograms by including `dendrogram="none"` in your call to `d3heatmap()`; see pp. 2-3 in [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/d3heatmap/d3heatmap.pdf). As for the reordering, try adding `Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE` to the call as well and see if that does it.

Comment: @ulfelder, It's correct. Thank you.

Comment: Did that fix the reording problem, too? If so, I'll make it into an answer.

Comment: Were you going to accept the answer on your other question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off the dendrogramming by including `dendrogram="none"` in your call to `d3heatmap()`.

To leave the cells in the original order, also include `Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE` in that call.

So:

```
d3heatmap(df2, scale = "column", colors = "Blues",
    dendrogram = "none", Rowv = FALSE, Colv = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Do you know how to put the rownames to the left?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't. I've used this function a few times before and found it frustratingly finicky. You might find `geom_tile()` in `ggplot2` easier to manipulate.